# Add content based on what div is above

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a customization, and can't change the HTML. Unfortunately it's terrible.

It has the following format:

```
<div>Thursday 28-02-2015</div>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
//And so on
```

And I need to extract the content from the `div`, and add it as an `:after` to each table cell. So a bit of jQuery comes in handy.

```
var a = $("div").text();
$("td").append("<span>" + a + "</span>");
```

The trouble is, the HTML repeats itself. So how can I make the jQuery choose the right div? The right div is the first div above the table.

Sample HTML

```html
<div>Thursday 28-02-2015</div>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<div>Friday 29-02-2015</div>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<div>Saturday 30-02-2015</div>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
```

Expected Output

```html
<div>Thursday 28-02-2015</div>
<table><tr><td>Some content<span>Thursday 28-02-2015</span></td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content<span>Thursday 28-02-2015</span></td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content<span>Thursday 28-02-2015</span></td></tr></table>
<div>Friday 29-02-2015</div>
<table><tr><td>Some content<span>Friday 29-02-2015</span></td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content<span>Friday 29-02-2015</span></td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content<span>Friday 29-02-2015</span></td></tr></table>
<div>Saturday 30-02-2015</div>
<table><tr><td>Some content<span>Saturday 30-02-2015</span></td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content<span>Saturday 30-02-2015</span></td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content<span>Saturday 30-02-2015</span></td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Realized I overcomplicated this. You can simply loop through each `div` with an `.each()` function and grab its contents to add into the tables after it.

You can use `.next()`, repeated as necessary, to get the next however many tables.

```js
$(function(){
  $('div').each(function(){
    var a = $(this).text();
    $(this).next().find('td')
    .add($(this).next().next().find('td'))
    .add($(this).next().next().next().find('td'))
    .after('<span>' + a + '</span>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Thursday 28-02-2015</div>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<div>Friday 29-02-2015</div>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<div>Saturday 30-02-2015</div>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></table>
```